# How do i use string to get user Console Input

Tags: c++

Im working on a c++ programm which needs user text input per terminal as a variable

I have tried cin << input;

but text output is only shown as a 0

```
int input;
std::cin >> input;
std::cout << input;
```

I expected the text as output but i only got a 0

Comment: `input` is an integer.  Why do you expect it to store text?  Sounds like you could use a [good C++ book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)

Comment: Recommendation: Rather than `std::cin >> input;`, write something like `if (std::cin >> input)`. This way you can test to see if your input was accepted. Eg: `if (std::cin >> input) { std::cout << input } else { std::cout << "Error!" }`

Comment: *"I have tried `cin << input;`"* - That wouldn't work regardless. Thankfully that's not what the later posted code does. Assuming a valid integer input value was performed, the posted code should reflect that value as output.  Second, your post should provide *exactly* what you offered as input.Since you have no error checking, anything other than valid `int` data will not extract, and leave `input` indeterminate.

Comment: @WhozCraig Actually in C++11 and above it will zero the destination on failed input.

Comment: @NathanOliver Sure. Lets hope the OP is using something from the most recent decade, because a hundred million people still using the travesty of TC++ certainly aren't. It was interesting the standards committee added that, because without checking the stream state you *still* don't know if the zero was due to a failed extraction or an actual zero-read. Therefore, since you have to check it anyway, why bother with a default value. Thanks for the clarity, btw. Nice.

Comment: `input` should either be `std::string` or `char*`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Integer can not take text as input. You need string in order to read text input form  user.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
   string text;
   cin>>text;
   cout<<text;
    return 0;
}
```

This program will  input text from  user. But cin extraction always consider white spaces as termination. For example cin in will only read "this" from "this is an apple string". In order to read complete string use getline() function. The above program can be written as

```
 #include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
   string text;
   getline(cin,text); // will read white spaces to
   cout<<text;
    return 0;
}
```